# Passing Multidimensional Arrays from PHP to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I am trying to pass my multidimensional array from php to javascript,

```
$settingsArray = array('genSettings' => array(), 'settings' => array());

$settingsArray['genSettings'] = array(
    "userName" => array("error" => false, "msg"=> ""),
    "email" => array("error" => false, "msg"=> ""),
    "firstName" => array("error" => false, "msg"=> ""),
    "lastName" => array("error" => false, "msg"=> ""),
    "style" => array("error" => false, "msg"=> ""),
    "pwd" => array("error" => false, "msg"=> "")
);


<script  type="text/javascript">
    var settings = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(<?php echo json_encode($settingsArray) ?>));
    alert(settings); 
    alert(settings.genSettings);
    alert(settings['genSettings']); 
</script>
```

the output is for all the alerts returns [object Object]

> I've tried the following:
>
> `var settings = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($settingsArray) ?>);` returns SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 ->
> [object Object]
>
> `var settings = <?php echo json_encode($settingsArray) ?>;`  all
> returns [object Object]

with JSON.stringify

```
var settings= JSON.stringify(<?php echo json_encode($settingsArray) ?>);
alert(settings); 
alert(settings.genSettings);
alert(settings['genSettings']);
```

the first alert return:

> ```
> {"genSettings":{"userName":{"error":false,"msg":""},"email":{"error":false,"msg":""},"firstName":{"error":false,"msg":""},"lastName":{"error":false,"msg":""},"style":{"error":false,"msg":""},"pwd":{"error":false,"msg":""}},"settings":[]}
> ```

while the rest returned undefined, I still unable to grab the individual values in JavaScript as
`settingsArray.genSettings.userName` or `settingsArray['genSettings']['userName']` and so forth. As seen in my first attempt I JSON.parse the `JSON.stringify(<?php echo json_encode($settingsArray)?>)` and returns `[object Object]`.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong to get the results in javascript. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the the whole object, use only `stringify`. To print other things inside, reparse the JSON and stringify what you need to print:

```
var settings = JSON.stringify(<?php echo json_encode($settingsArray) ?>);
alert(settings); 

settings = JSON.parse(settings); // Required to access objects inside

alert(JSON.stringify(settings.genSettings)); // Stringify what you access to read it
alert(JSON.stringify(settings['genSettings']));
```

Comment: Is there a way, where I don't need to use JSON.stringify() everytime I want to read the value?

Comment: @Brandon No. `Stringify` is required. Is there a reason you can't use it?

Comment: Nope, just thought it might be redundant since I would be making several calls for different values at a time was hoping can just do settings.genSettings.userName.error. Thank you though just what I needed.